# Undefined variable in Laravel - passing array from controller to view

Tags: php, laravel

I just installed Xdebug in Phpstorm, and I'm having all kinds of problems with it. I'm running PHP-version 7.1.8 and Xdebug version 2.5.5). I keep getting below-written error.

It's the part about `Undefined variable: csvfile` that I don't get ... I've passed it from my controller to my view - and I can even display it and treat the data in that array (with `print_r` for instance):

**The error from Xdebug**

```
/usr/local/bin/php /Users/[USERNAME]/path_to_project/resources/views/home/minor.blade.php
@extends('layouts.app')
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: csvfile in /Users/[USERNAME]/path_to_project/resources/views/home/minor.blade.php on line 19

PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/[USERNAME]/path_to_project/resources/views/home/minor.blade.php:0
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/[USERNAME]/path_to_project/resources/views/home/minor.blade.php on line 19
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/[USERNAME]/path_to_project/resources/views/home/minor.blade.php:0
@section('title', 'Minor page')

@section('content')
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="m-t-lg">
                    <h1>
                        Testarea
                    </h1>


Notice: Undefined variable: csvfile in /Users/[USERNAME]/path_to_project/resources/views/home/minor.blade.php on line 19

Call Stack:
        0.0029     359184   1. {main}() /Users/[USERNAME]/path_to_project/resources/views/home/minor.blade.php:0


Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/[USERNAME]/path_to_project/resources/views/home/minor.blade.php on line 19

Call Stack:
        0.0029     359184   1. {main}() /Users/[USERNAME]/path_to_project/resources/views/home/minor.blade.php:0


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**All my web-routes:**

```
Route::get('/testcsv', 'TimeRecordController@importCsv')->name("test");
```

**My TimeRecordController:**

```
class TimeRecordController extends Controller {

//  public function index() {
//      return view( 'home/minor' );
//  }


    function csvToArray( $filename = '', $delimiter = ',' ) {
        if ( ! file_exists( $filename ) || 
             ! is_readable( $filename ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        $header = null;
        $data   = array();
        if ( ( $handle = fopen( $filename, 'r' ) ) !== false ) {
            while ( ( $row = fgetcsv( $handle, 10000, $delimiter ) ) !== false ) {
                if ( ! $header ) {
                    $header = $row;
                } else {
                    $data[] = array_combine( $header, $row );
                }
            }
            fclose( $handle );
        }

        return $data;
    }


    public function importCsv() {

        $file = public_path( 'file/test.csv' );
        $csvfile = $this->csvToArray( $file );

        return view( 'home/minor' , compact('csvfile' ) );
    }
}
```

**My `home/minor`-view:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Minor page')

@section('content')
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="m-t-lg">
                    <h1>
                        Testarea
                    </h1>

                    <?php
                    date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Copenhagen' );

                    xdebug_break();
                    $counter = 0;
                    foreach($csvfile as $value){
                        if($counter < 10){
                            $new_date = explode('.', $value['Date']);
                            $new_date = $new_date['2'] . '-' . $new_date['1'] . '-' . $new_date['0'];
                            $start_datestamp_raw_string = $new_date . 'T' . $value['Check-In'];
                            $end_datestamp_raw_string   = $new_date . 'T' . $value['Check-Out'];

                        $start_stamp = new DateTime($start_datestamp_raw_string);
                        $end_stamp = new DateTime($end_datestamp_raw_string);
                        echo $start_stamp->format('H:i') . ' to ' . $end_stamp->format('H:i');

                        $datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
                        $datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
                        $interval = $start_stamp->diff($end_stamp);
                        echo '<br />';
                        echo '<br />';
                        echo 'Diff: ' . $interval->format("%H:%I");
                        echo '<br />';
                        echo '<br />';

                        }
                        $counter += 1;
                    }

                    ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

---

**UPDATE**

As requested, then here is the output of `dd( $csvfile )`, written just above the `foreach`-statement in the view. There are 172-lines, so I've just expanded two of them:

```
Testarea

array:173 [▼
0 => array:14 [▼
  "Date" => "29.07.2017"
  "Day" => "Sat"
  "Check-In" => "07:36"
  "Check-Out" => "07:40"
  "Total" => "00:04"
  "Total (decimal)" => "00.07"
  "Task" => "AA - Bathroom Break 170125"
  "Task ID" => "151"
  "Task Extra 1" => ""
  "Task Extra 2" => ""
  "Client" => "Nece (Con)"
  "Work unit notes" => ""
  "Day Total" => "16:22"
  "Day notes" => "regular"
]
1 => array:14 [▼
  "Date" => "29.07.2017"
  "Day" => "Sat"
  "Check-In" => "07:40"
  "Check-Out" => "08:05"
  "Total" => "00:25"
  "Total (decimal)" => "00.42"
  "Task" => "AA - Eat 170126"
  "Task ID" => "180"
  "Task Extra 1" => ""
  "Task Extra 2" => ""
  "Client" => "Nece (Uncon)"
  "Work unit notes" => ""
  "Day Total" => ""
  "Day notes" => ""
]
2 => array:14 [▶]
3 => array:14 [▶]
```

Comment: try dd( $csvfile ) and show us what are you getting ?

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi: I've included that in the post now.

Comment: try to dd on your blade as well    {{dd($cvcfile)}} see if you are getting the result same even from the blade